# alert message while account merge

Tags: apex, trigger, account, merge

i wondering there is way to alert messaging, while account merge.

for example, account A must be master record. account B must be merge record

i wish the message appear like "you can't merge !!" when user attempt merge A to B.

thank you

Comment: instead of alert, why not validation rule ?

Comment: but how do you decide which shouldn't be master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are many possibilities. In case you directly want to remove the "merge permission", then as far as I know it would be enough to **remove the delete permission**.

Nonetheless, if you want users to maintain that permission but still prevent the merging, you can go for a **validation rule** like commented in [this post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DJ0hAAG).

```
AND(
NOT(
ISNEW()),
NOT(
ISBLANK(UniqueID)))
```

Another option is, as always, a **trigger** which depending on your scenario it might be better. Nonetheless, as best practices go, do try to always solve things declaratively before programmatically.